# Cargo Publish uses different dependency version

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I do `cargo publish` of my library it fails to compile the project because for a some reason it uses different version of a dependency. But if I do `cargo build` it works fine.

I see that for `cargo publish` it uses two different version of one of the dependencies:

```
   Compiling bitcoin v0.27.1
   Compiling bitcoin v0.28.1
```

And it fails later because one of the dependencies uses 0.27.1 and another 0.28.1.

The dependency is specified as `bitcoin = "=0.27.1"` in `Cargo.toml`. If I look into `Cargo.lock` file I see only version `0.27.1`. I.e. only one entry, no other versions in `Cargo.lock`. `cargo tree` shows only version `0.27.1` as well. And `cargo build` uses only `0.27.1` for compilation.

It's absolutely unclear where from the `0.28.1` comes from during the `cargo publish`

How I can tell `cargo publish` to not use `0.28.1` and stick to version in the `Cargo.lock`? I tried `--locked` and `--frozen` but I doesn't make any effect.

UPDATE
One of the dependencies has defined `bitcoin = ">= 0.27"` and it seems that Cargo tries to use the most up-to-date version `0.28.1` only because it fits that criteria for that lib. And `0.27.1` for others. That obviously would not work. How to enforce it to use one version?

UPDATE 2:
There is the whole tree of the conflicting versions `cargo tree --all-features`:

```
├── bitcoin v0.27.1
.
├── emerald-hwkey v0.2.0
│   ├── bitcoin v0.27.1 (*)
│   ├── hdpath v0.6.1
│   │   ├── bitcoin v0.28.1
```

Where `hdpath:0.6.1`'s `Crate.toml` accepts any version via:

```
bitcoin = { version = ">= 0.27", optional = true }
```

So it's unclear why Cargo tries to upgrade this particular version and makes everything incompatible to each other.

UPDATE 3:
It seems that it works if I use a local version of `hdpath` with enforced `">= 0.27, < 0.28"`. But I don't want that because `hdpath` by itself doesn't have a reason for such restriction and works fine with any of the versions.

So I just need to make sure it uses the version compatible with the parent project. Is there any way?

Comment: You can override the version for that dependency. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html

Comment: Still.. this sounds a bit weird, like something else is still going on.

Comment: Note that `Cargo.lock` should not be relevant here. For a library crate, you shouldn't be including it in your git repo, and it's _possible_ (though I don't know if this is actually the case) that `cargo publish` ignores `Cargo.lock`, since users of your crate won't have it either.

Comment: I tried to do `[patch.crates-io] bitcoin="0.27.1"` but it doesn't work because _"patches must point to different sources"_

Comment: Yeah, my suspicion that `Cargo.lock` is ignored and `publish` always tries to use a latest version when possible. Which doesn't work. And it's unclear how else I can enforce a range of compatible dependencies, and in particular dependencies for intermediate dependencies

Comment: If you remove the `Cargo.lock` file and `cargo build`, does it use one version?

Comment: Yes, if I remove `Cargo.lock` then `cargo build` also fails

Comment: So it seems it's a bug in Cargo https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10733 and https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9029